# change content inside page content instead from sidebar in react-router v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, single-page-application

I have a sidebar and content. When I click list in sidebar, the content changes correctly, but what if I change the route from content itself? I have a problem from here.

[image: screen shot]

When I click "Bubblegum" link in sidebar, it shows content h1 with 'Bubblegum' words. Below that I have a link name 'Pax'. My hope is that when I click that link ('Pax') it changes the main content to the new content.

Code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

// Each logical "route" has two components, one for
// the sidebar and one for the main area. We want to
// render both of them in different places when the
// path matches the current URL.

// We are going to use this route config in 2
// spots: once for the sidebar and once in the main
// content section. All routes are in the same
// order they would appear in a <Switch>.
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    sidebar: () => <div>home!</div>,
    main: () => <h2>Home</h2>
  },
  {
    path: "/bubblegum",
    sidebar: () => <div>bubblegum!</div>,
    main: () => {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Bubblegum</h2>
          <Link to="/bubblegum/pax">Pax</Link>
        </>
      );
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/bubblegum/pax",
    sidebar: null,
    main: () => {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Pax</h2>
        </>
      );
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/shoelaces",
    sidebar: () => <div>shoelaces!</div>,
    main: () => <h2>Shoelaces</h2>
  }
];

export default function SidebarExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            padding: "10px",
            width: "40%",
            background: "#f0f0f0"
          }}
        >
          <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none", padding: 0 }}>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/bubblegum">Bubblegum</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/shoelaces">Shoelaces</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <Switch>
            {routes.map((route, index) => (
              // You can render a <Route> in as many places
              // as you want in your app. It will render along
              // with any other <Route>s that also match the URL.
              // So, a sidebar or breadcrumbs or anything else
              // that requires you to render multiple things
              // in multiple places at the same URL is nothing
              // more than multiple <Route>s.
              <Route
                key={index}
                path={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
                children={<route.sidebar />}
              />
            ))}
          </Switch>
        </div>

        <div style={{ flex: 1, padding: "10px" }}>
          <Switch>
            {routes.map((route, index) => (
              // Render more <Route>s with the same paths as
              // above, but different components this time.
              <Route
                key={index}
                path={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
                children={<route.main />}
              />
            ))}
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Here's the sandbox playground:

[Code Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-sidebar-forked-1hxjso?file=/example.js)

I tried my best but for now, but I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that routing within the `Switch` component works a very specific way. The `Switch` component returns ***the first*** matching `Route` or `Redirect` component. You've listed the `"/bubblegum"` content prior to the `"/bubblegum/pax"` content in the `routes` array. This means whatever content is rendered by the route on `"/bubblegum"` will ***always*** be matched first and render the incorrect content when really on a `"/bubblegum/*"` sub-route.

When rendering routes inside the `Switch` component you should render the routes in inverse order of path specificity. In other words, the ***more*** specific routes should be rendered before ***less*** specific routes.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    sidebar: () => <div>home!</div>,
    main: () => <h2>Home</h2>
  },
  {
    path: "/bubblegum/pax", // <-- more specific route path
    sidebar: null,
    main: () => <h2>Pax</h2>
  },
  {
    path: "/bubblegum", // <-- less specific route path
    sidebar: () => <div>bubblegum!</div>,
    main: () => (
      <>
        <h2>Bubblegum</h2>
        <Link to="/bubblegum/pax">Pax</Link>
      </>
    )
  },
  {
    path: "/shoelaces",
    sidebar: () => <div>shoelaces!</div>,
    main: () => <h2>Shoelaces</h2>
  }
];
```

Additionally, since the `routes` config array has potentially `null` sidebar or main components you will want to filter the `routes` array accordingly when rendering.

```
{routes
  .filter(({ sidebar }) => !!sidebar)
  .map((route, index) => (
    <Route
      key={index}
      path={route.path}
      exact={route.exact}
      children={<route.sidebar />}
    />
  ))}
```

...

```
{routes
  .filter(({ main }) => !!main)
  .map((route, index) => (
    <Route
      key={index}
      path={route.path}
      exact={route.exact}
      children={<route.main />}
    />
  ))}
```

[image: Edit change-content-inside-page-content-instead-from-sidebar-in-react-router-v5]

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, thanks for helping me. i have one question. how to do 'back and forth' page from pax to bubblegum?

Comment: @github.arief Can you clarify what "how to do 'back and forth' page from pax to bubblegum" means?

Comment: i mean, from pax back to bubblegum again

Comment: @github.arief The sidebar already has a link to `"/bubblegum"`, and the bubblegum page has a link to `"/bubblegum/pax"`, I guess the pax page could render a link back to `"/bubblegum"` or the user could use the sidebar to get back there. You could create a bubblegum layout route that renders a bubblegum navbar and outlet for the bubblegum and pax pages. It mostly depends on what you want the UX to be.